# Build Netbeans from sources: Can't open the Netbeans sources in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I have downloaded the Netbeans sources (v8.1) to make a small change in Netbeans.
So I followed the instructions on that page:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/WorkingWithNetBeansSources

- Imported the Netbeans sources with Mercurial: `$ hg clone http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/`. Works.
- Build a new fully functional Netbeans Dev Version from the commandline with ant. Works.

According to the instructions I should be able to do that: "The whole source tree has NetBeans project metadata so you can just use NetBeans to develop NetBeans". But that doesn't work.

That's my environment: Netbeans 8.0.2 64Bit, Java 8, Ant 1.9.x, Mercurial 3.6.2. The sources are from 8.1.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the modules (like `ant.browsetask` or `ant.debugger`) do have a directory `nbproject`, but this directory contains only two files: `project.properties` and `project.xml`. Shouldn't there be more files? Are these two files sufficient for Netbeans, so it can be recognized as a project?

So how can I open the Netbeans sources in Netbeans?

[image: Netbeans sources I've cloned with Mercurial]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution by myself.
Netbeans needs to have the plugin 'Netbeans Plugin Development' installed. I uninstall it usually, because I don't do that, but now's an exception.